Will modulating an IR LED at higher frequency reduce its range? If so, why?
I'm working on developing a protocol for IR based communication. I came across this information that the range of my IR based communication network will reduce if I modulate the message signal at higher frequency of around 15 MHz? I know that the higher frequency have lesser range but why will carrier frequency matter if the signal is still being transmitted at 980 nm?

Bear in mind that if your objective in raising the carrier frequency is to increase the bitrate, then assuming your LED is driven at a constant power, you will transmit less energy per bit (energy=power x time). Therefore you’ll get less range for a given SNR at the receiver.

thank you  for your reply @MartinC

Best guess, something in your signal chain isn't fast enough and your effective output power drops due to it.

The modulation frequency must be in the receiver's capture range,
and most receiver designs are wideband.   That implies that
a high modulation frequency is associated with wideband receiver noise
along with the signal.   It may be necessary to use a brighter infrared
transmitter, or accept lessened range of reception, in that case.
Transmitted information can never exceed the signal-plus-noise/noise
limit set by Shannon.   Wideband noise may be filtered (and/or swamped with stronger signal) for reliable communication.  Both narrowband
IR sensors and narrowband modulation schemes serve this purpose also.

You won't have reduced range if you use parts and circuit suitable for 15 MHz modulation. They just needs to be quite performant parts and circuits, carefully selected and designed. For example hobbyists have transferred 10 Mbps Ethernet successfully over hundreds of meters optically.
But if you use parts and circuits not capable of 15 MHz then range will be reduced. The techniques of driving the LED matter. The LED cannot be turned on and off instantly, the PN junction has capacitance and your driving circuit must also limit the peak current to charge and discharge the capacitance, so to reach the bandwidth you want you need high enough current and low enough capacitance, and even the inductance will limit how quickly the charges can be moved.
If the LED is not driven fast enough, it's basically equivalent of having it lit up at some DC bias with smaller AC brightness variation instead of turning fully on and off.
